# special z character?

Tags: math-mode, letters

I see the character

[image]

in many papers, which looks different than the standard math character $z$.  Why is this character used, and what is the command for it?

Comment: This is a “swash z” that's found in some variations of Times. I doubt that a reader would spot a special symbol.

Comment: how do i draw it though @egreg

Comment: Please let me know if I closed your question in error.  It is an italic `z` found in the times font.

Comment: There are some differences between Times Roman and Times New Roman. For instance, in italic mode the `z` character's bottom stroke has a "swash" for Times Roman but is plain-horizontal for Times New Roman. See [How to set font to Times instead of Times New Roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/518971/5001) for more information about the differences between these two fonts.

Comment: The swash-tailed "z" has been excluded from traditional math journals because it is not readily compatible with subscripts.